# Magento cart page is not showing

Tags: magento, checkout, cart

My Magento cart page is not showing at all. It just comes up with a blank page. Previously this site was developed by another developer and He has disabled the Checkout process. Now I cannot find which settings he has done to stop the checkout process.

Can anyone tell me what are the possibilities to stop the default module from working.

Also every thing else is coming right on the cart page. Header and footer and all the things just that it is not rendering the html for cart block. The Content just came up empty, with no HTML.

Comment: please open your admin panel and then System/Configuration/Advanced and there is a tab Disable Modules Output ....check the Mage_Checkout is enable or disable ?

Comment: Have you tried re-enabling the default theme and see if the checkout process is working? That narrows the search right away. `Admin > System > Configuration > General > Design` set to `default`.

Comment: Yes I have done all these things and nothing is working. Even I have disabled the custom extensions one by one but that did not help either.

Comment: ok please enable your log and then show me what you are getting.

Comment: @AleemAhmad: do you know how to enable the log ?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs as well. Because there is no error at all. The module is just disabled and do not know how.

Comment: @AleemAhmad: which module is disable ?....if you are talking about the mage_checkout then there is only one way to enable and disable the module which i already mention in my answer

Comment: try to rename Checkout template directory in active package/theme like app/design/frontend/[Active Package]\[Active Theme]\template\checkout
make sure Checkout directory must exists in base directory

Comment: Replace or rename your active theme checkout folder and copy the base checkout folder[base/default/template/checkout] and past it in ur active theme folder. and also replace the active theme checkout.xml file with base checkout.xml file.

Comment: Can you please upload the screenshot? Try to check the checkout.xml for unclosed comments

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. My issue is resolved now. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @AleemAhmad Please share if you think this may be helpful for others.

Comment: I will add an answer to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please open the adminpanel and then go to the

```
System/Configuration/Advanced
```

there is a tab Disable Modules Output and then enable the Mage_checkout module

Answer (score 1):

As I have told you the previous developer have disabled the modules. But that was not the case the developer have installed some extensions to disable the checkout process but that does not work very well. Then he tries to delete the extensions the wrong way so the entries that were made by those extensions was still in the database table "core_config_data".

And these values are being used by the left over files of the extensions ans he has overridden the magento core files for that. I just copy and replace the core magento files and also cleared the table "core_config_data" table and all things got working once again.